# Port selection and recognition in Inter-Process Communication (IPC)

Tags: ipc

We are developing two Windows applications (say A and B); totally different applications, but they will transfer some data with each other using an IPC mechanism. A will send a query with the label of the data in B. Application B is actually a plugin to a larger application, and B will get the data from that application with the queried label.

With this in mind, here is also a need for a communication protocol between A and B. We were thinking of using a TCP-based communication. As we are using Qt, we can use QTcpServer and QTcpSocket classes. The communication will be done locally on the localhost.

One challenge that we are then going to face is scalability. The user may open multiple instances of A and B, and each instance of A would need to know which instance of B it should get the data from. Thinking further in the future, we are also planning to develop plugins for other applications (C, D, E, ...) from which A will also get data.

If I understand correctly, an A instance and B instance will need to exclusively talk through one port, which cannot be shared with another process. While Qt can seem to dynamically identify and assign an unused port, **how does the other application know which port to communicate through**?

I would also appreciate any suggestion or best practice to do this, or how anyone implements a protocol for this kind of communication. Performance is critical, and we hope to be able to achieve real-time response (data changes in B can be quickly reflected in A). Both applications are written in C++. If there is a Qt-based solution, that will be great. That said, I am open to other solutions.

Comment: If your question is not about Qt then do not use it since you are limiting the scope of your question. On the other hand the button to create the publication says "Ask Question", does not say "Ask Questions" because if you ask many questions there is a risk that the publication closed for too broad.

Comment: OK thank you! Let me simplify the question then. The primary question is actually the one on the port selection and recognition.